# Make doctrine load auto_increment value after save

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine for database abstraction. Now I'd like to get the `auto_increment` primary key from the freshly-created (and `save()`'d) object - but `$obj->toArray()` shows me that the field is empty after calling `save()`.

Is there a flag that I'm not aware of that does this? Or do I really have to query the object from the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have the autoincrement flag set when setting up your object in the `setTableDefinition()` method (or related YAML config file).  If this flag isn't set, then Doctrine won't know to update it.  You should have something that looks like this:

```
 $this->hasColumn('id', 'integer', 4, array(
                  'type' => 'integer',
                  'length' => 4,
                  'fixed' => false,
                  'unsigned' => true,
                  'primary' => true,
                  'autoincrement' => true //this flag right here
             )
 );
```

Comment: Aaah yea that was it! I accidentally wrote auto_increment.. I think doctrine should warn if a parameter isn't valid :( But Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

Call `refresh` on the record instance before the `toArray`.

Comment: Is this a 2.x or 1.2 feature? Because I'm on 1.1 and it doesn't make the primary key field appear. (but the refresh() method is there..)

Comment: Maybe it is only 1.2 - i thought it was 1.x though.